# ListView Items sorting?

Tags: wpf, sorting, listview, .net-4.0

I have a ListView which contains four column, In which i am adding items dynamically as :

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
lvi.Background = ... color you want ... ;
lvi.Content = new {Server = "test1", .... };
listViewResult.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Now I want to sort this dynamically generated ListView on a perticular column click.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found article [here](https://ligao101.wordpress.com/2007/07/31/a-much-faster-sorting-for-listview-in-wpf/) which explain the custom sorting.

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing=”True”

First you need to specify the above property to true in your ListView, (this is the default value for ListView in WPF).

Then next, you need to use custom sorter, instead of SortDescriptions as described in my earlier blog. The key is using the CustomSort property of ListCollectionView:
ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myListView.ItemsSource);

Then in your ColumnHeader click event handler, you add something like the following:

view.CustomSort = sorter;
myListView.Items.Refresh();

Where sorter is a custom class you implement the IComparer interface.
```